# dvdrip - cannot extract

Tags: 12.04, dvd

I am unable to extract dvds in dvd::rip. When I try, the job progress dialog just says there is an error. I found a log file, but I don't see any indication of what the error is in it.
I checked the Debug -> Check Dependencies and that is fine.

I cannot post images due to reputation.

```
Thu Jan 16 15:28:40 2014        Project hhhhhh created
Thu Jan 16 15:28:43 2014        Start job 'Read TOC (lsdvd|tcprobe)'
Thu Jan 16 15:28:43 2014        Start job 'Read TOC (lsdvd)'
Thu Jan 16 15:28:43 2014        Executing command: execflow lsdvd -a -n -c -s -v -Op \/dev\/dvd 2>/dev/null && echo EXECFLOW_OK
Thu Jan 16 15:28:43 2014        Not enabling PSU core, because this movie has only one PSU.
Thu Jan 16 15:28:43 2014        Start job 'Read TOC (tcprobe)'
Thu Jan 16 15:28:43 2014        Successfully read DVD TOC
Thu Jan 16 15:28:43 2014        Copying IFO files from /media/MILES_DAVIS to /home/hal/dvdrip-data/hhhhhh/tmp/ifo
Thu Jan 16 15:28:43 2014        Job 'Read TOC (lsdvd|tcprobe)' finished
Thu Jan 16 15:28:44 2014        Job 'Read TOC (tcprobe)' finished
Thu Jan 16 15:28:44 2014        Job 'Read TOC (lsdvd)' finished
Thu Jan 16 15:28:48 2014        Start job 'Rip selected title(s) / chapter(s)'
Thu Jan 16 15:28:48 2014        Start job 'Process title #1'
Thu Jan 16 15:28:48 2014        Start job 'Rip - title #1'
Thu Jan 16 15:28:48 2014        Executing command: rm -f /home/hal/dvdrip-data/hhhhhh/vob/001//hhhhhh-???.vob && execflow -n 19 tccat -t dvd -T 1,-1,1 -i \/dev\/dvd | dvdrip-splitpipe -f /home/hal/dvdrip-data/hhhhhh/tmp/hhhhhh-001-nav.log 1024 /home/hal/dvdrip-data/hhhhhh/vob/001//hhhhhh vob  | tcextract -a 0 -x pcm -t vob | tcscan -x pcm && echo EXECFLOW_OK
Thu Jan 16 15:28:52 2014        Executing command: execflow tcprobe  -i /home/hal/dvdrip-data/hhhhhh/vob/001/ && echo EXECFLOW_OK
Thu Jan 16 15:28:52 2014        Job 'Rip - title #1' finished
```

Any thoughts?
Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried alternative dvd rip software such as OGMRip? Do these also fail or just dvd::rip?

Comment: Hmm. I can't even play DVDs in VLC anymore. I see this error in the vlc log: "main error: ES_OUT_RESET_PCR called". I will search for that error online...

Comment: I found this post: http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2178960
Looks like libdvdcss2 got uninstalled somehow?? Anyway, running sudo /usr/share/doc/libdvdread4/install-css.sh seems to have things working again. Thanks for the quick suggestion to get me on the right track.

Comment: If you have found a solution, write it up as an answer to your own question.

Answer (score 1):

I found this [Ubuntu Forum post](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2178960). Looks like libdvdcss2 got uninstalled somehow?? Anyway, running

```
sudo /usr/share/doc/libdvdread4/install-css.sh
```

seems to have things working again.